# How to use 'or' operator in regex properly?

Tags: javascript, regex, alternation

I am trying Javascript's regular expression. 
I understand that '`|`' is used to or-ing two regular expression. 
I created a regex `/^a*|b*$/`, and I want it to detect any string that contains only charater of 'a' or 'b'.
But when I try `/^a*|b*$/.test('c')`, it produces `true`? 
**What I am missing understading of '`|`' operator?**

Here's my code:

```
let reg = /^a*|b*$/;
< undefined
reg.test('c');
< true
```

Comment: Note that even the "corrected" version of this regex will match `a`, `aa`, `b`, `bb`, etc, but **not** `abab` etc.  You need to use something like `[ab]*` to fix this.

Comment: yes, I know that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`|` has very low precedence. `^a*|b*$` matches

- either `^a*`
- or `b*$`

i.e. either a string beginning with 0 or more 'a's or a string ending with 0 or more 'b's. (Because matching 0 'a's is allowed by the regex, any string will match (because every string has a beginning).)

To properly anchor the match on both sides, you need

```
/^(?:a*|b*)$/
```

(the `(?:` `)` construct is a non-capturing group).

You could also use

```
/^a*$|^b*$/
```

instead.

Note that both of these regexes will only match strings like `aa`, `bbbbbb`, etc., but not `aba`. If you want to allow the use of mixed a/b characters in a string, you need something like

```
/^(?:a|b)*$/
```

Comment: @NghĩaNguyễn You should accept the answer if it really helps solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The **OR** in your example will split the expression in these alternatives:
`^a*` and `b*$`.

You can use groups to delimit the alternatives

Something like

```
/^(a*|b*)$/
```

This will match empty strings, strings that contains only `a` characters and strings that contain only `b` characters.

If you're looking to match strings that contain both `a` and `b` characters, you can use something like:

```
/^[ab]*$/
```